# Laravel Cache in database conflicting

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am using laravel's Cache facade to build up booking data prior to storing the booking in the database.

I generate the booking in the cache by using the below function which creates a UUID this is then as the booking reference.

Once I have generated a reference, I then set the booking postcode as below

Nearly every other booking has conflicting postcodes which is a postcode from another booking in the cache.

For example when the first customer comes along their postcode is set correctly. The second customer will set their postcode and this is overriding the first customer's postcode even though I am using the unique booking reference.

The Cache is stored in the databsse

```
CACHE_DRIVER=database
```

---

BookingController.php

```
public function generateBooking() : JsonResponse
{
    return $this->respondSuccess([
        "booking_reference" => $this->booking->generate()
    ]);
}


public function setPostcode(string $bookingReference) : JsonResponse
{
    $booking = $this->booking->setReference($bookingReference)->get();

    $booking->setPostcode($this->request->postcode);
}
```

Booking.php

```
public function generate() : string
{
    $this->setReference(Uuid::generate(1));
    $this->store();
    return $this->reference();
}

public function setReference(string $reference)
{
    $this->reference = $reference;
    return $this;
}


public function reference() : string
{
    return $this->reference;
}


public function store($lastUpdated = true)
{
    if ($lastUpdated) {
        $this->lastUpdated = Carbon::now();
    }

    $expiresAt = now()->addMinutes(240);

    $bookingAsArray = $this->parser->toArray($this);

    Cache::put("bookings:".$this->reference(), $bookingAsArray, $expiresAt);
}


public function get() : Booking
{
    $booking = Cache::get("bookings:".$this->reference());

    return $this->parser->fromArray($this, $booking);
}


public function setPostcode($postcode, $shouldStore = true)
{
    $address = Address::make([
        "postcode" => $postcode
    ]);

    if ($this->address) {
        $address = $this->address;
        $address->postcode = $postcode;
    }

    $this->address = $address;

    if ($shouldStore) {
        $this->store();
    }
}
```

BookingParser.php

```
public function toArray(Booking $booking) : array
{
    $parsedBooking = [
        "reference" => $booking->reference()
    ];

    if ($booking->address()) {
        $parsedBooking["address"] = $booking->address()->toArray();
    }

    return $parsedBooking;
}

public function fromArray(Booking $booking, array $bookingArray) : Booking
{
    $booking->setReference($bookingArray["reference"], false);

    if (array_key_exists("address", $bookingArray)) {
        if (array_key_exists("postcode", $bookingArray["address"])) {
            $booking->setPostcode($bookingArray["address"]["postcode"], false);
        }
        $booking->setAddress($bookingArray["address"], false);
    }

    return $booking;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Session for personalized information instead of Cache. Caching is great for speeding up requests for everyone.

Comment: Where is `setPostcode` stored and how is it related to the cache?

Comment: How would a session improve my current setup?, I require to be able to loop through the cached bookings stored on the server which I am not sure I can do with sessions

Comment: @apokryfos the `setPostcode` is stored in a class called "Booking.php" and I persist the booking class to the cache by transforming it to an array.

Comment: You have some black box code here and not a clear connection between the functions. Try to update your question with a [minimal complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly does `$this->reference()` return?

Comment: @apokryfos I have updated my question to hopefully better reflect what I am asking... @DigitalDrifter `$this->reference()` returns a unique string used to reference a booking

Comment: Assuming `string $bookingReference` in `setPostcode` is set correctly for each distinct customer (i.e. it's different) then I don't really see why it should behave the way it does.

Comment: @apokryfos yes the booking reference is coming through unique for each customer. Could it be something to do with needing to lock the cache?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem since each cache entry is a row in the database table. As long as you're using a different key it shouldn't really be trying to update the same row.

Comment: @apokryfos there are two rows in the database table and both have unique keys therefore in my eyes should not overwrite. Do you have any other suggestions?